# Question about android date formatting

Tags: android

There are two source codes of android, but I don't understand what they mean.
And the phone can't change the dateformat, the dateformat is always `wday_month_day_no_year`.

```
mTimeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getContext());
        mDateFormatString = getContext().getString(R.string.full_wday_month_day_no_year);
        refreshTimeAndDateDisplay();
        updateStatusLines();



public void onTimeChanged() {
        refreshTimeAndDateDisplay();
    }

    private void refreshTimeAndDateDisplay() {
        mDate.setText(DateFormat.format(mDateFormatString, new Date()));
    }
```

what's the meaning of `mDateFormatString = getContext().getString(R.string.full_wday_month_day_no_year);`?

Well,I change the DateFormat,But in the lockscreen,that is not showing the date by the dateformat I set.So I don't know what's wrong with it.In the lockSreen it always show the date by "full_wday_month_day_no_year" format.

please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `format()` method takes a string as a first parameter. In this particular case, the string is defined in the resources, specifically in the file located at `res/values/strings.xml`, as

```
<string name="full_wday_month_day_no_year">E M d</string>
```

or similar

The reference for DateFormat: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html

and for string resources: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: How can I change the dateformat by my setting. This fix the dateformat.

Comment: How can I change the dateformat by my setting.                     This fix the dateformat.

Comment: Use any other string instead, e.g. `DateFormat.format("dd-MM-YYYY", new Date())`, or change the value in that resource file.

Comment: But the DateFormat is the string-array,                           MM-dd-yyyy,dd-MM-yyyy,yyyy-MM-dd,how can i set one of it,the lockscreen will show it.

Comment: I have no idea what are you talking about

Comment: Sorry,I don't talk clear. In the phone,there is dateformat setting. There are three dateformat:MM-dd-yyyy,dd-MM-yyyy,yyyy-MM-dd.If i set one of them,the lockscreen will show the dateformat I set .

Comment: But are you still talking about an app or this is about the phone settings and the framework lockscreen?

Comment: I think it's about the phone settings and the framework lockscreen.

Comment: You won't be able to change that without creating a whole new framework, or editing smali: neither is an easy option! What you might do is to change the phone locale (in the phone settings). That may change the date format in the lockscreen.